# Create firefox extension or addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to create a Firefox extension or Add on. I am totally new for this. I saw lots of links but not found good link. So please suggest me some good links as like a beginner developer for addon.

Comment: So you need to learn `XUL` good link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Tutorial and this good link for hello world firefox extension https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Getting_Started_with_Firefox_Extensions you can also download different extension and read code to see how developper make her app @Joomla Developer

Comment: Webextensions are really easy, you should try them out - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/ - You can also use the google chrome addon docs for WebExtensions

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or **other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.